# Image is uploading and pasting but not saving in CKEditor

Tags: image, ckeditor, fckeditor

I'm using ImagePaste plugin to paste the image from word. But the image is not showing after the uploading.

[When I paste the image it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L86S.png)

But when I retrieve the image than it doesn't appear.

Comment: By default, CKEditor does not include a file browser plugin. See more here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_howtos_file_upload

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To automatically upload pasted image, you'll need:

1. A file manager (like [CKFinder](https://cksource.com/ckfinder)).
2. [Upload Image](http://ckeditor.com/addon/uploadimage) plugin.
3. A properly configured CKEditor.

The configuration could look like this:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor2', {
    extraPlugins: 'uploadimage,image2',
    height: 300,

    // Upload images to a CKFinder connector (note that the response type is set to JSON).
    uploadUrl: '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&responseType=json',

    // Configure your file manager integration. This example uses CKFinder 3 for PHP.
    filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
    filebrowserUploadUrl: '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images'
} );
```

There's an [official guide](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/fileupload.html) about uploading files using CKEditor.